# Windows Maximum Length of Key Container Name

Tags: windows, encryption

Can anyone confirm that the maximum length of a key container name in Windows is 260 characters.  I expect this to be the size because the value is stored as a file, but I have not found the specific answer as of yet.

In the meantime I'll see what trial and error I can do.

Updated:

I did trial and error with aspnet_reiis.exe and discovered that 260 is indeed the maximum length.  261 and above causes key creation failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is one, or at least you shouldn't rely on there being one.  From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379886.aspx):

> The key container name. This is a null-terminated string that identifies the key container to the CSP. **This name is independent of the method used to store the keys. Some CSPs store their key containers internally (in hardware), some use the system registry, and others use the file system.** When dwFlags is set to CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT, pszContainer must be set to NULL.

Piratically speaking you would probably be safe with 256 as that is the maximum length of both a file name and a registry key.